# how to Array inside Array Data in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, mongodb

I am trying to get array value in BLADE file. My array is shown below but I am not able to get value inside array.

I have get [student_levels]=> [level]  Data

laravel Code

```
foreach($items as $item)
{
    echo $item['student_levels']['level'];
}
```

$items is Array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [_id] => 5c1e4295b0dace71ec62e325
            [email] => dhavalpansuriya1195@gmail.com
            [franchisecode] => MELHH
            [title] => Mr
            [firstname] => dhaval s
            [lastname] => patel
            [gender] => Male
            [age] => 16-18
            [phone] => 9601354880
            [address] => rajkot
            [city] => Ahmedabad
            [country] => India
            [tempcode] => hUmoEF
            [studentid] => HTNKLF
            [updated_at] => 2019-11-21 13:32:31
            [created_at] => 2018-12-22 19:26:37
            [student_status] => eda
            [student_levels] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => 5c8b11d2b0dace2f9a044d86
                    [student_id] => HTNKLF
                    [teacher_id] => 5c1e1ab5b0dace716e429654
                    [level_name] => recomended_level
                    [level] => Level 1
                    [comments] => hhbhhhh
                    [exam_type] => eda
                    [student_course] => 
                    [updated_at] => 2019-03-15 08:15:38
                    [created_at] => 2019-03-15 08:15:38
                )

        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array inside an array..so you can use `foreach` loop as

```
 @foreach($items as $item)
   {{$item['student_levels']['level']}}
 @endforeach
```

Or directly

```
{{$items[0]['student_levels']['level']}}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

It seems your array is returning an array of students, you have an extra level in your array. So to fetch the first student level, you need to use the following code:

```php
echo $item[0]['student_levels']['level'];
```

Maybe the code that fetches this data could be optimized to only fetch a single student, could you post this code?